# Write JSON data using Python on Heroku

Tags: python, json, heroku

I have a Python script(setup as a daily job) that writes the last timestamp from the results of an API request to a json file. For next API call, I will read that timestamp, and add that as a query parameter to fetch results only after that timestamp. First thing I get the JSON content like:

```
jsonFile = open("records.json", "r")
data = json.load(jsonFile)
jsonFile.close()
```

Then I get the last stored timestamp like:

```
last_timestamp = data["last_reading"]
```

I then get new results, modify the 'data' object and write the JSON back to the file like:

```
data["last_reading"] = new_timestamp
with open("records.json", "w") as jsonFile:
    json.dump(data, jsonFile)
```

This works perfectly on my local system. However, when I deploy my python script and the json file on Heroku, the updating does not work. I can verify that the code opens the json file, reads records from it but cannot write them back for some reason. Any ideas on why this might be happening? Workarounds are also welcome. Is there a particular configuration/option that I have to add to Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

This [reference](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-faq#can-i-read-from-and-write-to-the-file-system) might answer your question: .

You can use external storage such as the options described [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/data-management), all of which seem overkill for what you are trying to do, but that seems to be the state of play. [Heroku Redis](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-redis) seems the easiest of those options, and suitable if you also need to persist other data. Another option is AWS S3.